# Django, react & fetch - submitting CSRF token on post request

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I am creating a webapp with Django (Rest) and templates that are spiced up by react components. These reactcomponents are connected toDjango_restframework API's.

The 'GET' requests are working just fine, but so far I've been unable to get the post requests to work. The problems seems to be centered arround:

```
{detail: "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
```

These are the steps that I have taken:

1 - I've enabled `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True` in my settings.py

2 - I've added the CSRF tag in my django template, like so (I am using django webpack-loader, hence the other tag)

```
<div id="create_root"></div>
{% render_bundle 'main_create_assessment' 'js' %}
{% csrf_token %}
```

3 - I've added a function to fetch the CSRF from the cookie

```
function getCookie(name) {
    if (!document.cookie) {
      return null;
    }
    const token = document.cookie.split(';')
      .map(c => c.trim())
      .filter(c => c.startsWith(name + '='));

    if (token.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return decodeURIComponent(token[0].split('=')[1]);
  }

  const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')
  console.log(csrftoken)
```

(The 'console.log' statements show me that the 'csrftoken' variable is assigned the correct value,  yet the post requests keeps failing on a 403 / missing/incorrect csrf token error. )

4 - I've added the csrf information to the header of the post request, like so:

```
  fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: this.state.title
    })
   })
  }
```

Again, my console.log statements seem to indicate that I am supplying the correct token, yet the 403 error keeps persisting. Could someone enlighten me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Thats not a solution.
Imagine that situation... You have a car. Thats car have a broken doors. So as a solution you remove that doors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem!

My sollution was correct, however I had to remove the `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True` from the settings.py

And remove the `{% csrf_token %}` tag from the template.

The POST requests work after these changes.

Comment: It is not solved. You simply have removed the security protection provided by csrf. Now csrf will not be used.